# Use Hibernate as a library

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have a jar library that have some class with  persistence  annotations. I need no hibernate.cfg.xml in my jar library so I create hibernate.cfg.xml in destination project that import jar .I guess  this hibernate.cfg.xml use configuration file like any.hbm.xml that specify class in jar(any.hbm.xml exists in jar library ) library (I guess this solution with `<mapping resource="any.hbm.xml"/>` in hibernate.cfg.xml in destination project). How to write any.hbm.xml for jar library and how to use it in hibernate.cfg.xml?

I write this any.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <mapping class="com.test.Vehicle"/>
    <mapping class="com.test.driver"/>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this error for it:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2081)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2061)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2014)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1929)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1908)
    at ir.mersada.db.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 50; Element type "mapping" must be declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1906)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the persistence.xml is a better choice.

```
<persistence xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="UNIT_NAME" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.test.Vehicle</class> 
        <class>com.test.driver</class>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: how to import it to hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: I forget: You don't use mapping xml if you can use annotations. OK, it could be off-topic, sorry.

Comment: I need import jar library that contain annotative class in another project

Answer (score 0):

The SaxParser gives you a clear answer: the mapping element doesn't valid.

But I'm confused. If you use annotation and you don't need cfg.xml in the project then the simply way if you won't use cfg.xml.